# Is it possible to host a Sencha-powered mobile website on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Amazon S3 static website hosting sounds really tempting - simple to use, reliable, and the price is right.

However, everything I've read so far talks about a "static" website. It seems that by static they mean no server-side processing. Sencha framework seems to fit the bill as it's pure JS framework.

Given that all website assets will be on S3 and no server-side processing is required (contact form will submit to a different server), can a fully featured Sencha mobile site live on S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it will work for the same reasons you mentioned...and as you say, its very cheap, so there is little risk in giving it a whirl.

Comment: There's always that nagging thing called free time ;) But it's only fair that I do some work for this. Thanks!